# How to locate in a huge list of numbers, two numbers where xi=xj?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, hash

I have the following question, and it screams at me for a solution with hashing:

**Problem :**

Given a huge list of numbers, `x1........xn` where `xi <= T`, we'd like to know 
whether or not exists two indices `i,j`, where `x_i == x_j`.
Find an algorithm in `O(n)` run time, and also with expectancy of `O(n)`, for the problem.

**My solution at the moment** : We use hashing, where we'll have a mapping function `h(x)` using `chaining`.

First - we build a new array, let's call it `A`, where each cell is a linked list - this would be the destination array.

Now - we run on all the `n` numbers and map each element in `x1........xn`, to its rightful place, using the hash function. This would take `O(n)` run time.

After that we'll run on `A`, and look for collisions. If we'll find a cell where `length(A[k]) > 1` 
then we return the `xi` and `xj` that were mapped to the value that's stored in `A[k]` - total run time here would be `O(n)` for the worst case , if the mapped value of two numbers (if they indeed exist) in the last cell of `A`.

Comment: Hashing will also require `O(n)` space. Is this allowed? (considering it's a *huge* list of numbers)

Comment: @Goo: Nothing is said about the space , then I guess that that goes without saying .

Comment: Is T < N ? Are you allowed to shuffle / alter / distroy the array ?

Comment: Hashing cannot really give you O(n) run time, only O(n) *expected* run time. Imagine what happens if all the numbers map to the same hash value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The same approach can be ~twice faster (on average), still `O(n)` on average - but with better constants.

No need to map all the elements into the hash and then go over it - a faster solution could be:

```
for each element e:
  if e is in the table:
      return e
  else:
    insert e into the table
```

Also note that if `T < n`, there must be a dupe within the first `T+1` elements, from [pigeonhole principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle).

Also for small `T`, you can use a simple array of size T, no hash is needed `(hash(x) = x)`. [Initializing T can be done in `O(1)`](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2008/08/23/initializing-an-array-in-constant-time/) to contain zeros as initial values.

Comment: +1 Since the algorithm indicates that `xi <= T`, it's likely they had a plain array in mind.